# How do I show and hide loader to show more posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How do I show the loader when a user clicks on load more posts button and more posts are loading and hide it after the posts have been loaded successfully. Then I want to again show the loader when user clicks on load more posts button

```js
$("#lmb").click(function(e) {
  $('#lmi').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="lmb" type="button" style="background-color: #f44336;width:98%;border-radius:6px;border:2px solid #4a235a;">Load More Posts <img src="http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/151309/loader.gif" width="2%" height="2%" id="lmi" style="display:none;"></button>
```

Comment: How do you load posts? from where are you getting posts ?

Comment: Is this an async load?  Might try this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
<button id="lmb" type="button" style="background-color: #f44336;width:98%;border-radius:6px;border:2px solid #4a235a;">Load More Posts 
  <img id="loader" src="http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/151309/loader.gif" width="2%" height="2%" id="lmi" style="display:none;">
</button>
```

jQuery post method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lmb").click(function(){
        $('#loader').show();
        $.post( "URL", function( data ) {
         $('#loader').hide();
      }); 
    });
});
```

There are done, fail & always methods also you can handle it

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Comment: thank you for the help
this helped me achieve the functionality i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are the posts loaded but I suppose that when you click the button, you launch an AJAX request to the server and the server returns the posts... So you just need to hide the loader in the callback function.

JQuery:

```
$.ajax("where/I/get/posts.php", {
    method: get,
    //more options
    success: function(response) {
        //add posts
        $('#lmi').hide();
    }
}
```